# How do I access an object's eigenclass in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

In Ruby, it's possible to access the eigenclass (or "singleton class") of an object by reopening it. This is particularly useful for defining "private class methods":

```
class Foo
  class << self
    private
    def declarative_method_name
    end
  end

  declarative_method_name
end

# Foo.declarative_method_name => ERROR!
```

However, in Crystal this is not syntax:

```
Syntax error in ./test.cr:2: expecting token 'CONST', not '<<'

  class << self
        ^
```

Is there another (or indeed any) way to achieve this in Crystal currently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no eigenclass, or more commonly called singleton class in Ruby these days (given there's `Object#singleton_class`), in Crystal.

However defining class methods and calling them on the class level is supported:

```
class Foo
  private def self.declarative_method_name
    puts "hey"
  end

  declarative_method_name
end
```

https://carc.in/#/r/1316

The `def self.` construct here is specialized by the compiler and there's no more general concept beneath it, yet.

Answer (score 0):

How would you make a super classes' new method private while still allowing it's subclasses' to be public?

```
class Foo
  private self.new; end
end
class Bar < Foo
end
Bar.new #=> error: private method 'new' called for Foo:Class
```

Comment: Well never mind. Crystal is doing something odd. Apparently you just have to add `super` to Foo's `self.new` method.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting here that unlike in Ruby, class variables don't transcend inheritance.  In Ruby the following code has a strange side effect...

```rb
class Foo
  @@var = 'foo'
  def var
    @@var
  end
end
class Bar < Foo
  @@var = 'bar'
end
puts Foo.new.var
```

It'll return 'bar' despite the fact that we modified the class variable on Bar.  In crystal it returns 'foo' meaning that another reason we'd access the eiganclass, to store and read class level state safely, isn't necessary in crystal, we can just use class variables.